# Are if/switch evaluations atomic?

Tags: java, android, asynchronous

Let's say i start and `AsyncTask` and hold a reference to it:

```
AsyncTask task = new SomeAsyncTask().execute();
```

And then at some point, while the task is still running, i perform the following:

```
if(task.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING) {
    task.cancel(true);
}
```

Can the status of the `AsyncTask` become `FINISHED` **after** `task.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING` returns `true` **and before** `cancel()` is called?

In other words, is it possible that using the code above `cancel()` will get called on a finished `AsyncTask`?

Comment: Yes, this is possible.

Comment: Yes, that's a possibility. You can use wasCancelCalled() in your task to make more checks

Comment: use onPostExecute if you want to do something after the task has finished

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this is possible, that's the nature of async' programming.

Your call to `cancel`, however, will be benign should the task have finished between those two statements.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it may happen, so the best way is used to observe the changes for the value of `STATUS` variable. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html, for more details check the link.

Comment: How would you use this for monitoring an Android `AsyncTask`'s state?

Comment: I think it has already been addressed in the comments. Check once.